# Ember not supporting Handlebars' ability to use each on an object

Tags: ember.js

I am attempting to use the each helper over an object and receive:

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]
```

Using latest versions of Ember(1.0) and Handlebars. My best guess is that Ember doesn't support bindings over an object yet and that's the reason for the assertion firing.

Can someone confirm please?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you not just index the value you want? Or you could always make it into an array if you don't want to use the values? I can't imagine that there will ever be support for using #each over an object.

Comment: Maybe he's trying to loop over an object and print each property and it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are correct, Ember itself has a dependency on the item being an array.  Since Ember tries to be performant and not re-render/re-calculate items that have already been done it adds an array observer and watches items change one at a time instead of re-rendering an entire collection.

The each helper itself actually supports iterating over an object (the key's in the object)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(context, options) {
  var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
  var i = 0, ret = "", data;

  var type = toString.call(context);
  if(type === functionType) { context = context.call(this); }

  if (options.data) {
    data = Handlebars.createFrame(options.data);
  }

  if(context && typeof context === 'object') {
    if(context instanceof Array){
      for(var j = context.length; i<j; i++) {
        if (data) { data.index = i; }
        ret = ret + fn(context[i], { data: data });
      }
    } else {
      for(var key in context) {
        if(context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if(data) { data.key = key; }
          ret = ret + fn(context[key], {data: data});
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if(i === 0){
    ret = inverse(this);
  }

  return ret;
});
```